# Allowing restricted accounts to use gmail/hangouts

Tags: gmail, nexus-7, restricted-profiles, google-hangouts

I'm pondering deploying a fleet of nexus 7 tablets, but I'm running into a few hiccups on managing the fleet.

I would like to do the following:

- Use multiple restricted accounts on each tablet
- Allow access to the browser
- Block google play store (easy enough with restricted accounts)
- Allow each account access to individual gmail/hangouts for communication (not an option with restricted accounts - as it appears it is blocked and uses the primary user's info)

Is there any work around to allow restricted accounts to access gmail/hangouts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between a "user profile" and a "restricted profile" is that a restricted profile doesn't have its own Google account, which is needed for Gmail and Google+ Hangouts. A restricted profile with a Google account in it is just a normal user account.

If you want to restrict access to features in a normal user profile, you need to use [device-administrator](/questions/tagged/device-administrator) software to impose a security policy. This will also allow you to remotely/centrally manage each device.